# Selenium c# - API Massa de testes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, team-foundation-server, selenium-webdriver

Boa tarde, pessoal.

Estou com um problema e a ajuda de vocês é importante.
Tenho uma massa de testes escrita no TestManager online e meus scripts estão em visual studio 2015. Os meus scripts do VS se loga no TestManager online e via Xpath pega os dados da massa. No entanto, precisava fazer de outra forma.
Essa parte de se logar no testmanager não deve aparecer, ou seja, poderia ser utilizada, acredito, alguma api que pegasse os parâmetros sem precisar se logar no TestManager. 
Vocês podem me ajudar com isso ? Hoje meu código está assim:

```
drivertfs.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[4]/div/input")).SendKeys("anderson.alves@verotthi.com.br");
Thread.Sleep(5000);

drivertfs.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[6]/div/input")).SendKeys("Ao198119");
drivertfs.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/form/div[2]/input")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(10000);

drivertfs.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/ul/li[4]/span/span/div/a")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(6000);
drivertfs.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[5]/a")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(10000);

drivertfs.FindElement(By.LinkText("Parameters")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(10000);

var CloudPadraoAmbAdd = drivertfs.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]".Trim()));
String CloudPadAmbAdd = CloudPadraoAmbAdd.Text;
var AmbAdicP = drivertfs.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]".Trim()));
String AmbAdicionalP = AmbAdicP.Text;

drivertfs.Close();
```